# Argument of type "unsigned char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks, decoder

I was using the [Decoder](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bcse/1834878/raw/7483fb72abbb32aa69b853fdcc9f6f72e7568677/scrdec18.c) for Microsoft Script Encoder. It works perfectly well when I run it in Codeblocks. But when I run it in Visual Studio, it shows me the following errors
**Snippet 1:**

```
char decodeMnemonic(unsigned char *mnemonic)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (entities[i].entity != NULL)
    {
        **if (strcmp(entities[i].entity, mnemonic) == 0)**
       **//Error 1: cannot convert argument 2 from 'unsigned char *'
       // to 'const char *'**   
        return entities[i].mappedchar;
        i++;
    }
    printf("Warning: did not recognize HTML entity '%s'\n", mnemonic);
    return '?';
}
```

I had to integrate the Decoder in a program, so instead of passing the filenames as command line arguments, I have given their filepaths myself in the code.

**Snippet 2:**

```
    int main()
    {
        unsigned char *inname = "C:\\Users\\Karthi\\Desktop\\Project Winter 2018-19\\poweliks_sample\\poweliks_encoded_js.bin";
        unsigned char *outname = "C:\\Users\\Karthi\\Desktop\\Project Winter 2018-19\\poweliks_sample\\decoded1.txt";
        unsigned int cp = 0;
   //**Error 2: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const char [87]' to 'unsigned char *'**
```

Comment: String literals are read only and therefore const. Use const in your type definitions.

Comment: The second error is quite clear: The string literals are arrays of *constant* characters. They will decay to pointers to `const char`, i.e. `const char*`.

Comment: The first error is also quite clear, you have `unsigned char*` but the compiler wants `char*` (the `const` is less relevant in this case). So now the big question for you: *Why* do you use **`unsigned`** `char`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen String literals are "read-only" in C, in C++ they are actually constant to begin with (arrays of `const char`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` (for `unsigned char*` to `const char*`). But if you go from `const unsigned char*` to a non `const` type, you have to use `const_cast` first, since `reinterpret_cast` cannot cast away a `const`.

The paragraph below gives a brief overview, why your code did not work.

According to [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (similiar to other C standards), a string literal has static storage duration and its type is `char[]` The standard says:

> If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

The reason why your program worked, when you used `argv` is, that `argv` is not considered as an array of string literals. This means you can modify them.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the solutions for your problems:

**Snippet 1:**
strcmp is a method to compare two C Strings. It expects const char* types.

> int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
>   You have two option to solve it:

1. Declare your method like this

   ```
   char decodeMnemonic(const char *mnemonic)
   ```
2. Use C++Strings and declare your method like this

   ```
   char decodeMnemonic(std::string mnemonic)
   ```

If you use the second solutions you have to call the c_str()-Method to use it in strcmp

```
if (strcmp(entities[i].entity, mnemonic.c_str()) == 0)
```

Or you use only C++-String: read here how to use it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

**Snippet 2:** You can't use it like this because you have string literals which are arrays constant characters.
Please use C++-Strings. You work with C++, so use his features (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdstring-class-in-c/)

Anyway if you want to use it C-like: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings

```
char c[] = "abcd";
char c[50] = "abcd";
```

Or with const (C++)

```
char *str1 = "string Literal";
const char *str2 = "string Literal";
```